# Objects Within Objects in Java

Tags: java, oop, object

I've been given a coursework assignment where  I have to build a prototype hotel booking system, in accordance with the specification, which is as follows:

> **You will need at least three classes:**
>
> **Hotel**
>
> This should store all the essential information about a hotel,
>   including a name and some rooms.
>
> **Room**
>
> This should store the number of beds in a room.
>
> **Bed**
>
> This should store the size of a bed (i.e. single or double).

I'm totally confused about where to start!

I was under the impression that objects could not be contained within other objects.

For example, let's assume we instantiate a "Hotel" object. How would we then instantiate "Room" objects, and within that object, "Bed" objects?
How are these objects being stored? How do we interact with them *indirectly*, from another object?

Comment: If I understand you right, the question seems to be very basic and maybe you should read a tutorial about Java and oop first. Some explanation anyway: Objects can contain other objects. It is done with *member variables* / *attributes*. You can use a constructor to initialize the variables or set the values by using methods.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you don't need to nest classes into other classes, which are called inner classes, unless the work that a class takes care of can be chunked into small units that never need to be known outside it's parent class.

It sounds like the concept you want to look into is Composition.  It's when an object holds a reference to another object.

```
public class Room {

    private boolean isVacant;

    public Room() {
        isVacant = true; // The room starts vacant
    }

    // Pretend there is a way for clients to check in and out of the room

    public boolean isVacant() {
        return isVacant;
    }
}

public class Hotel {

    // Using composition, I can make an instance of one class 
    // available to the methods of another
    private Room room101; 

    public Hotel(Room room101) {
        this.room101 = room101;
    }

    public boolean isRoom101Vacant() {
        return room101.isVacant();
    }
}
```

Our hotel may not be very useful having only one room, but this example shows how you can "compose" one object into another.  Methods of `Hotel` can now use methods of it's `Room` instance known as room101.  You will want to think about how your rooms are structured, and how you want to represent it within your Hotel class.  A few objects used to store collections of other objects include `ArrayList` and `HashMap`.

**Edit**:

`this` is a fairly difficult concept to understand before you understand what a class is compared to an instance of that class (an object).  In the constructor of my sample Hotel class, I have a variable of type Room called `room101`.  And outside of the constructor is an instance field of the same type and name.

Java will always refer to a variable or reference of the nearest scope.  So if I have a method reference called room101, how can I refer to that other one declared outside the constructor, at instance level?  That's where `this` comes in.

```
public class ThisExample {

    // This is a separate variable at the instance level
    // Lets call this global in the comments
    private int a; 

    public ThisExample() {
        // This is a separate variable in the method level, 
        // lets call this local in the comments
        int a; 

        a = 5; // our local is now assigned 5

        this.a = 10; // Our global is now assigned 10

        this.a = a; // our global is now assigned to 5

        a = this.a * 2; // our local is now assigned to 10 
    }
}
```

In short, `this` refers to "this" instance of a class.  It's a way for an instance of a class to refer to itself as if from the outside.  Just like how another object would refer to `room101`'s method as `room101.isVacant()`.  A method in the Room class would similarly do `this.isVacant()` for the same effect.

And as a final note, if there is only one declaration of a symbol within a class.  The `this` keyword is implied.  So Room can call it's own method just as well without it as long as there is no other conflicting symbols of the same name. (This doesn't occur with methods as much as with instance fields/local variables)

Hopefully this helps clear things up a bit!

Comment: Starting to make more sense!
Could you briefly explain why you are using "this" in the constructor and assigning the variable to itself?

Comment: @MartinRand I expanded my answer to elaborate a bit on the topic of 'this'.  Hopefully this helps clear things up!

Comment: I've started working on the classes. Would you kindly mind discussing a few other things in chat with me? You seem to know what you're talking about.

Comment: @MartinRand Sure.  If you create a room and post the link I'll join if I'm still around.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is how to model some real world concepts into code.

It appears that the core of your problem can be stated as **a Guest can book a Room**.

I don't want to do your work for you, so let me start by asking **how you would write that in code**? After that, we can address the "Hotel" and "Bed".  Is this a major assignment or just a quick question?  Your implementation would depend on this.

A rule to learn and apply is:

> An action on an object in the real world, becomes a method of that object in an Object Oriented approach.